# Disabling single dots in ToC lines (one dot only between title and page)

Tags: table-of-contents

In the Table of Contents (ToC) when the title is long, occasionally LaTeX inserts only one dot between the title and the page number, which I find ugly. Is it possible the disable the insertion of a single dot but keep more dots? An example:

```
This is a short title . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 12
This is a long title and only one dot is inserted . 12
```

The latter one is ugly, it would look nicer without the dot, as:

```
This is a long title and only one dot is inserted   12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tocloft package provides many ways to alter the toc. Its model of spaces is given in the package documentation in Figure 1:

[image: toclof spacing model]

With that I can only see to increase `\@dotsep` so you get rid of single dots, if you don't have double dot's turning into single ones, afterwards. Otherwise increasing or decreasing margins and indents may help. You may play a litte with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{5}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Short title}
\section{This is very very long long long ultra longer ultra even long}
\end{document}
```

with normal spacing:
[image]
with larger spacing:
[image]